# Limits of two variables

Tags: calculus

Using $\delta-\epsilon$ approach can someone help me prove that the limit is equal to 1? 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{e^{xy}}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: Please provide [additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and the community. Some forms of context include background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick $\varepsilon>0$, and suppose $x^2+y^2<\delta$ where $\delta=f(\varepsilon)$ will be chosen later.

Then $|xy|\le\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}<x^2+y^2$ so $$\exp(-\delta)<\exp(-x^2-y^2)<\exp(xy)<\exp(x^2+y^2)<\exp(\delta)$$ and $1\le 1+x^2\le 1+\delta$.

Therefore $$\frac{e^{-\delta}}{1+\delta}<\left(\frac{e^{xy}}{1+x^2}\right)<e^\delta.$$ Thus we want to prove that for any $\varepsilon$, we can choose $\delta$ such that $$1+\varepsilon>e^\delta>\frac{e^{-\delta}}{1+\delta}>1-\varepsilon.$$
The left inequality is just $\delta<\ln(1+\varepsilon)$, and since the RHS is positive this is easily satisfiable.

If we set $\delta<\epsilon$, then the right inequality is satisfied when $e^{-\delta}>1-\varepsilon^2=(1-\varepsilon)(1+\varepsilon)>(1-\varepsilon)(1+\delta)$, that is, when $\delta<-\ln(1-\varepsilon^2)$. Since the RHS is positve, this is also satisfiable.

Thus the condition we place on $\delta$ is $$\delta=f(\varepsilon)=\min(\ln(1+\varepsilon),\varepsilon,-\ln(1-\varepsilon))$$